# SSRS Error: No Such Interface Supported

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a user that cannot export a report from a Sql Server Reporting Services (SSRS) report in any format.  This user is running Windows 7 x86 SP1 with IE8.

The user will bring up any report and it is displayed properly.  Then they will click on the Export button on the report toolbar (to export it to Excel or PDF) and this error is displayed:

**No such interface supported** - Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd  URI:http//reportserver...

Other people at this same location and simliar computer configuration have no issues.  The problem user has Office 2007 installed and it opens Excel files without issues.  Again, this user has this problem with ALL reports and no other user has this issue on any report.  Therefore, it is clearly a problem with something on his computer, but I really don't know where to start.

In desperation, I had him click on the "Print" button on the Report toolbar, as I know that triggers the download of some MS-required component.  He was able to print from there, but the above error remains.

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions or feedback.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely being a problem with IE8. I'd start with running Internet Explorer Troubleshooters:
(http://support.microsoft.com/kb/936211)

1. Exit all programs.
2. Click Start, and then click Control Panel.
3. Under System and Security, click Find and Fix Problems.
4. In the Task pane, click View All.
5. Click Internet Explorer Performance.
6. In the new window, click Next. 
   Note The troubleshooter runs and fixes all identified issues automatically.
7. Click Close.

Also, make sure the user has done an antivirus check recently.

Good luck.

Comment: I get the error but I am running IE10 on the client PC

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try just the following and see if the problem goes away:

**OPTION 1**

**Step 1: Fix IE**

Copy and paste the following in the command prompt running as an admin, then press :

```
"%systemroot%\system32\regsvr32.exe" "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\ieproxy.dll"
```

If you are running 64 bit windows, try this:

`"%systemroot%\system32\regsvr32.exe" "C:\Program Files> (x86)\Internet Explorer\ieproxy.dll`"

**OPTION 2**

If the above doesn't work, try the following two steps.

**Step 1: Re-register all DLLs**

Open a command prompt as an admin. Type the following command:

```
FOR /R C:\ %G IN (*.dll) DO "%systemroot%\system32\regsvr32.exe" /s "%G"
```

You will probably get some error windows popping up at this point, just ignore them all and close them when the command prompt stops churning.

**Step 2: Fix IE**

Copy and paste the following in the command prompt running as an admin, then press :

```
"%systemroot%\system32\regsvr32.exe" "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\ieproxy.dll"
```

If you are running 64 bit windows, try this:

`"%systemroot%\system32\regsvr32.exe" "C:\Program Files> (x86)\Internet Explorer\ieproxy.dll`"

Sources:

- http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itproui/thread/99e4ab4f-165d-4691-90dd-ab41a05d26a2
- http://forums.techguy.org/all-other-software/568737-solved-internet-explorer-wont-start.html